# Expected Value of First k Draws From a Weighted Distribution Without Replacement

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, expected-value

You have weighted distribution, *D* and draw from it without replacement - meaning that when a value is chosen it and all its associated weight is removed from the distribution. In probabilistic terms, the distribution would now be altered to *D*' where *p(k)*' = 0 and *p(i)*'= p(i|~k).

Now consider the first *m* draws from this distribution. Is there a non-computationally intensive way to compute the expected value? Obviously, to compute the expected value of the *i*th draw you can sum across all permutations, $\Gamma$, of previous choices, multiplied by $p(\gamma)$,and then multiply by $p(j|\gamma)$ and then multiply by the value:

$$\sum_{\gamma=0}^\Gamma \sum_{j=0}^N p(\gamma)p(v_j|\gamma)v_j$$

and then you sum the above formula from 1 to *m* (with *m* as a subscript of gamma) to get the expected value of the first *m* draws. However, this is clearly not ideal from an algorithmic standpoint. I believe it is $O(m*N^{m+1})$ (but the exact big O is not the focus here. It is clearly intractable as m and N get large).

My question is: is there a (computationally) better formula to use for this problem?

Comment: This is similar in concept to the [non-central hypergeometric distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noncentral_hypergeometric_distributions), which has a distinction between the Wallenius approach and the Fisher approach.  Your set-up is like the Wallenius approach,   but your question can be more easily answered if you were using the Fisher approach; unfortunately this could involve changing the weights in a complicated way involving $m$ and may not be practical.  You might find simulation gets you a better answer more quickly.

Comment: Weighted sampling without replacement is delicate to analyze. See the references in [1]. Monte Carlo would be an efficient way to estimate the mean, especially if the coupling in section 3 of [1] is used. For an exact computation

[1] https://www.jstor.org/stable/pdf/26496522.pdf

Comment: Yeah I was hoping to find an answer that did not involve simulation - not that I can't do it, but I already have a simulation set up and want to match results with a theoretical calculation.

Comment: @Henry I did consider a hypergeometric briefly, but did not know about the non-central hypergeometric. I'll look into it. Thanks!